# Series to watch to learn Portuguese?

Tags: duolingo, portuguese

I am currently learning Portuguese. I use Duolingo for it (which is working well, better as I expected). Now I think I can take on the next step (at least I hope!). I want purchase some series (for children of course) to learn the language even better. I was wondering what series are good for this purpose? So no street language or to fast speakers, just some with slow and good pronunciation?

Comment: Question might be better suited for [Portuguese Language](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't think this question is likely to be well-received on any SE site, as it's asking for subjective recommendations. Your best bet for things like this is to use a web site that is specifically designed for subjective recommendations. Amazon.com is a very popular one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for Children Portuguese Series, most of them are english/japanese animations dubbed, like X-Men Evolution, Justice League, Juniper Lee or Saint Seiya (Cavaleiros do Zodiaco in Portuguese).

But if you are looking for something more "native", then we have "Castelo Ra Tim Bum" or "Cocoricó".

Although, I'll not recommend you to watch children series because, well, I guess you can learn equal or better watching something that you like.

My recommendation is: Do you have any series that you like in your language (guess english) ? If so, why don't search for the same in Portuguese?

These possibly will be not easy like children series, but you will be accustomed with them because it's your favorite serie and you have already watched then a lot of times, don't you?

Comment: Are series and programs dubed in Brasil? In Portugal, they are not.

Comment: Yeah, they are dubbed in Brazil. Dubbing Market on Brazil is really strong. That's probably because only 27% of all brazilian people have fluency in another idiom (like english), and less than 18% have fluency in more than two. That mean 3/4 of the population only speak portuguese.
So, they really need things in portuguese.

Comment: I was asking about dubs vs subtitles, Carlos. In Portugal we get subtitles for everything in a foreign language, whether it's in Galician (which 99% of the people will understand) or in Russian (which 1% of the people will understand). But we never get dubs.

Comment: Oh I see. We have subtitles too but even so, many people don't have a good reading skill or don't like to read. Particularly, I prefer subs than dubs.
So, we have series and programs dubbed in Brazil.